# Visual studio bug when building

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, xaml, build

I have this wierd bug. When I build my project, it always pops up two instances of my singleton window. [Here is video](https://youtu.be/8ljaldURr2c) of it happening. Though I don't think it will help anyting, here is most of xaml of the window. In code behind are just events for mouse movement and a closing event.

```
<Window x:Class="Scoreboard.OutputWindow"
    d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance viewModel:ControlPanel}"
    Title="OutputWindow" Height="375" Width="540"
    Background="{Binding AppData.Settings.Color, Converter={converters:ColorToBrushConverter}}"
    MouseLeftButtonDown="football_MouseLeftButtonDown"
    MouseLeftButtonUp="football_MouseLeftButtonUp"
    MouseMove="football_MouseMove">
   <Window.InputBindings>
       <KeyBinding Modifiers="Control" Key="F" Command="{Binding FullScreenCommand}" />
   </Window.InputBindings>
   <Grid ...>
   </Grid>
</Window>
```

This window is a singleton in my ViewModel. I access it just from there. It happens on both of my two PCs.

EDIT:
When I remove it from the ViewModel, it doesn't happen anymore. But I sort of need it there.
EDIT2: [Here is](http://www.filedropper.com/testapplication) new project with that window. It doesn't behave exactly the same, but when you do some changes so it builds on debug, then on sturtup it creates another OutputWindow which isn't caught by breakpoint in constructor.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint in the constructor to see where the second instance is being created from?

Comment: It's just build, it doen't even start. Both instances should't be there.

Comment: Do you have any `Build Events` in the properties of the project? (Especially any post-build commands.)

Comment: Nope, there isn't a single one.

Comment: start with F11 and see when you get there, btw, how the window resides within its viewmodel? it should be the opposite

Comment: I really don't understand why the window doesn't show anymore if you remove it from the `ViewModel`. (It's just built and not run.) But then I may also ask the question: Why do you need an element of the GUI in your `ViewModel`? Having a `Window` inside of a `ViewModel` somewhat contradicts the whole MVVM concept. Can you perhaps upload a minimal stripped down version of your solution which also shows this kind of behavior?

Comment: Well I have two windows, the first main one holds the viewModel, so the viewModel doesn't know about this one. And I have a second one (yes, that one) which is for graphical output (ie. scoreboard in football). I am not that familiar with MVVM, so I don't know if I did it correctly since both windows need to have same ViewModel.
@Bijan - it doesn't even needs to be started for it to appear. Or said otherwise, it appears just on build, not on debug or release.

Comment: In MVVM you usually have a 1:1 relation of the `View` and its `ViewModel`. So you don't reuse a `ViewModel` in other `Views` (or window in your case). Then you have a `Command` that opens a new `Window` and sets its `DataContext` to an instance of the belonging `ViewModel`. If the data in these two windows is exactly 100% the same then you could have the same `ViewModel` - but even then your `ViewModel` doesn't need to know your window. Aside from this, that's almost surely not the root cause for your problem. I'll check your uploaded solution.

Comment: And just a hint: If you want to let me know that you wrote a new comment, you have to include @haindl in it or I won't get any notification.

Comment: @haindl Have you rebuilded it before you started it? Otherwise it won't start another instance of the window (at least for me). And I forgot to mention that I am using VS 2015.

Comment: Good news! I can exactly reproduce your problem and I'm now searching for the root cause. (I already know how to fix your code but now I really want to know why it happens in the first place.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause of your problem is the following line in your `ViewModel`:

```cs
public ViewModel()
{
    OutputWindow.IsEnabled = true;
}
```

This implicitly creates a `new OutputWindow()` in the getter of the property:

```cs
private OutputWindow _outputWindow;
public OutputWindow OutputWindow =>
    _outputWindow ?? (_outputWindow = new OutputWindow { DataContext = this });
```

The constructor then looks like this:

```cs
public OutputWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    Show();
}
```

This wouldn't be so bad at the moment but every time your `MainWindow` is instantiated, a new instance of `ViewModel` is implicitly created as well because of this code in the `MainWindow`:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <local:ViewModel />
</Window.DataContext>
```

Okay, that explains why the `OutputWindow` is showing up on start - but why does it show on build?
(Or in my case even if you open the XAML code of `MainWindow.xaml` in Visual Studio.)

If found the culprit and it's this little gem here which originates from `devenv.exe`:

```cs
TestApplication.exe!TestApplication.OutputWindow.OutputWindow() Line 15
TestApplication.exe!TestApplication.ViewModel.OutputWindow.get() Line 6
TestApplication.exe!TestApplication.ViewModel.ViewModel() Line 10
...
mscorlib.dll!System.Activator.CreateInstance(System.Type type, bool nonPublic)
...
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ClrObjectInstanceBuilder.Instantiate(Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.IInstanceBuilderContext context, Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNode viewNode = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNode})   Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.CreateInstance(Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.IInstanceBuilder builder, Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNode viewNode)  Unknown
Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNodeManager.Instantiate(Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNode viewNode = {Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.InstanceBuilders.ViewNode})  Unknown
...
XDesProc.exe!Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.DesignerProcess.RunApplication()
...
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

So, why does it happen?
On build or on open of the XAML designer, Visual Studio starts a thread and instructs `XDesProc.exe` to create a new instance of your `MainWindow`.
(`XDesProc.exe` is the component that is responsible for the XAML designer in Visual Studio and perhaps the designer should refresh if you build a project.)

And from there on, the way is as shown above:
A new `ViewModel` is created in the implicit `DataContext` of the `MainWindow` which implicitly creates a new instance of the `OutputWindow` in the getter of the property which in turn calls `Show()` on itself. And voilà, there you have your `OutputWindow` on screen!
In some cases there are even two `OutputWindows` showing but that's only because the designer (or maybe another component) is called two times.

So, **bottom line** - what do you need to fix your code?
There are multiple possible solutions.
Most important you should stop the implicit creation of the `OutputWindow` in the `ViewModel`. You can achieve this by doing one (or more) of the following:

- Remove `OutputWindow.IsEnabled = true;` in the constructor of `ViewModel`.
- Don't call `Show();` in the constructor of `OutputWindow`.
- Don't instantiate your `ViewModel` implicitly using `<Window.DataContext><local:ViewModel />`.

I think it's fair to say that it's just plain wrong to implicitly show a window if you just create an instance of a simple ViewModel. So, if you break this unlucky chain of implicit events then your problem will be gone forever.

Comment: Thanks, nice detailed description of what was happening. The `OutputWindow.IsEnabled = true` was there just so the getter gets called. As you wrote, I removed `Show()` from constructor and moved it after initialization of the `MainWindow` and problem solved. Kudos for you.

Comment: @Korhak You're very welcome! Glad I could help you!  :-)